# Compare lists of data options besides EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

I want to compare two lists of data and i absolutely tired of excel with its difficult to use formulas what are approach i can take? I could try something like WinMerge and it works, it gives visual only need to extract from list B values that are NOT in list A?

Excel spreadsheets are [here](https://www.upload.ee/files/16292139/Table_Compare.xlsx.html).

```
A  B
1  1
2  5
3  2
   4
  11
```

Comment: If you do not want to use Excel, please remove the `excel` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `FILTER()` & `COUNTIFS()` function:

[image]

---

```
=FILTER(F2:F6,COUNTIF(E2:E4,F2:F6)=0)
```

---

The above formula is related with the OP, and the one related with the `Excel File` will be as follows:

[image]

---

```
=FILTER(C2:C123,COUNTIF(A2:A71,C2:C123)=0)
```

---

Alternatively, can use `FILTER()` with `XMATCH()` function:

```
=FILTER(C2:C123,ISNA(XMATCH(C2:C123,A2:A71)))
```

---